# Use one implemented interface to instantiate Generic class with multiple interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a generic method which using multiple interfaces,

```
public T GetZonePrices<T>() where T : IRegionalZonePrice, INationalZonePrice, new()
{
// codes here
}
```

Then, I have a class that will be used to replace the T. It only implement one interface.

```
public class MarketRegionalZonePrice : IRegionalZonePrice
{
// properties here
}
```

How do you use the generic method by passing the class which only implemented one of the interfaces?

```
var result = GetZonePrices<MarketRegionalZonePrice>();
```

It gives me error,

> "The type .. cannot be used as parameter type 'T' in the generic type or method .. . There is no implicit reference conversion from .. to .. ."

Comment: You can't.  You have a type constraint on your generic method that `MarketRegionalZonePrice` doesn't meet.  This is why type constraints exist for generics.

Comment: Your requirement is that any class used as `T` has a parameterless constructor, and implements both `IRegionalZonePrice` and `INationalZonePrice`. `MarketRegionalZonePrice` doesn't so it won't work. How would you expect it to work if only one constraint was required? Should it just throw runtime exceptions when you call methods on a `T` that doesn't implement a method or property of a given interface?

Comment: As noted in the previous comment, your question is unclear. If the method doesn't use the members of the second interface, then you can just remove it from the constraints list. But if it does use those members, why in the world do you think the caller should be able to pass an object that doesn't implement that interface? The short answer is "you can't", which is true enough. But if you want some genuine help, you need to improve your question so that it's clear what you actually think should happen.

Comment: Probably what you want is an interface called ```IZonePrice``` which your more specific Interfaces ```IRegionalZonePrice``` and ```NationalZonePrice``` will inherit from then in your generic you can use ```IZonePrice```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can't.

What you could do though is:

```
public inteface IZonePrice 
{
// codes here
}
public interface IRegionalZonePrice : IZonePrice  
{
// codes here
}
public interface INationalZonePrice : IZonePrice 
{ 
// codes here
}

public T GetZonePrices<T>() where T :IZonePrice, new()
{
// codes here
}
```

Then this would work:

```
public class MarketRegionalZonePrice : IRegionalZonePrice
{
// properties here
}

...

var result = GetZonePrices<MarketRegionalZonePrice>()
```

if need be you can check the type of `T` with `T is IRegionalZonePrice` or `T is INationalZonePrice`

Is there much different between these interfaces? Because it almost looks to me that you overcomplicated your business model / logic?

You probably just need the interface`IZonePrice` and then your implementation will be `public class RegionalZonePrice : IZonePrice` and `public class NationalZonePrice : IZonePrice` with the respective different values for each Zone.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. It leads me to find a workaround to solve the problem.
It was complicated because I tried to combine a bunch of existing codes which have similar data models.